# Extra spacing around SfCircularChart

Tags: flutter, mobile, charts, syncfusion

first time asking a question here. I would like to how to remove the extra spacing around the `SfCircularChart` from `syncfusion_flutter_charts` package.

```
Container(
 // Wrapping around fixed size Container
 width: 200,
 height: 200,
 color: Colors.red,
 child: SfCircularChart(
  // Setting the margin to zero
  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
  series: <CircularSeries>[
   PieSeries<Category, String>(
    dataSource: dailyEarningList,
    xValueMapper: (Category data, _) => data.name,
    yValueMapper: (Category data, _) => data.value,
    dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(
     isVisible: true,
    ),
   ),
  ],
 ),
)
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPy44.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PieSeries<Category, String>(
            radius: "100",
            dataSource: [Category(["a", "b", "c"])],
            xValueMapper: (Category data, _) => "d",
            yValueMapper: (Category data, _) => 1,
            dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(
              isVisible: true,
            ),
          ),
```

The library has a radius parameter. It's a string. I do not understand why it's a string. In your example if you set it to "100", it will match the container.

Comment: It works! Thanks you for the fast response :D

Comment: Note that radius="100" works here since the container had size of 200 (=2*radius).  When the container would have size 300, the radius should be "150".   
Using "100%" would work in both cases (whichalso  explains why it is a String)